# How do I pin the Help Viewer for Visual Studio 2012 RC to the task bar?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

If I open the help viewer from within Visual Studio 2012RC and then use the "pin this program to taskbar" feature the icon that it creates doesn't work. When I attempt to open it I get an error message saying:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Help Viewer 2.0
---------------------------
The Help Viewer command line has missing parameters. Specify the
required parameters, or run Help Viewer by using the application 
shortcut. 

For help with command syntax and options, use the /? parameter.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, you need to provide the correct command line parameters which aren't being 
applied when you pin the help viewer.

To do this:
Right click the pinned icon and then right click the "HlpViewer" item and select "Properties".
In the dialog that opens change the "Target" value and add the following to the end:

```
/catalogName VisualStudio11 /locale en-US /sku 3000
```

This should fix it so that it opens the help viewer just like from the help menu in Visual Studio. I'm not sure what the sku number is exactly, this was for 2012 Ultimate RC.